# How to get format of currency using current culture information and validate that currency

Tags: c#

I have requirement where i have currency code and using that code i am finding the current culture of that currency and also symbol of that currency.

[image]
Here I have the ability to change the currency ISO code and if user changes the code according to that i am changing the currency symbol.

Now i want to find the format of that culture using currency ISO code.Which format that culture uses for currency.How can i find that?

And using that format i want to do the validation of currency.If user enter currency in wrong format then i want to give the validation how can i do that?

Comment: For getting currency format i have not tried anything.I am not getting idea how can i find the currency format using Currency ISO code.

Answer (score 2):

The `decimal` type, which is good for a currency, has the [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx) method that accepts the culture.

```
bool IsValidCurrency(string s, string tla, out value)
{
  var culture = CultureInfo
   .GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
   .Where(c => c.ISOCurrencySymbol == tla)
   .First();
  return decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, culture, out value)
}
```

Where `s` is the text representation of the currency value and `tla` is the ISO three letter abbreviation of the currency.